# Solve this functional equation with respect to $f$

Tags: functional-equations

Let $v\not= 1$ be a real number. Let $f(s)$ be real analytic on an open interval containing $v$ and $1$, with a zero of order $m\ge 1$ at $s=1$.

My **question** is: Can we solve this functional equation with respect to $f$:

$$f(sv)=\frac{(s-1)f'(s)}{f(s)}$$ where $s$ is in the proximity of $s=1$.

Comment: Something is obviously wrong or imprecise with this statement of the problem. If $v\ne1$, then we define $f(s)$ arbitrarily in a sufficiently small neighborhood of $1$ (the only requirements being that it is real analytic and has zero of order $m$) and then use your equation to define it in a neighborhood of $v$. So long as these neighborhoods have an empty intersection, we are done. This is if you require $f$ to be real analytic only near $1$ (and hence near $v$). If, however, you wish $f$ to be real analytic on $R$, then why require equation to hold only near $1$? It then holds everywhere.

Comment: @Vladimir: Yes,  Christian Remling is right. This is exactely my question.

Comment: These comments refer to an earlier version; I've edited, in order to clarify.